# Why does wcwidth return -1 with a sign that I can print on the terminal?

Tags: c, unicode, printing, widechar

Why does here `wcwidth` return "-1" (not a printable wide character) width "Ԥ" (0x0524)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int wcwidth(wchar_t wc);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

    wchar_t wc1 = L'合'; // 0x5408
    int width1 = wcwidth(wc1);
    printf("%lc - print width: %i\n", wc1, width1);

    wchar_t wc2 = L'Ԥ'; // 0x0524
    int width2 = wcwidth(wc2);
    printf("%lc - print width: %i\n", wc2, width2);

    return 0;
}

Output:

合 - print width: 2
Ԥ - print width: -1
```

Comment: The other thing I see in the docs is that the locale is important.  Any idea of those are both valid wide chars in the same/current locale?

Comment: What's the hex value of the house-looking-shape?

Comment: @xaxxon: LANG=de_DE.UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely U+0524 was not a valid character when your libc character database was created. It was added in Unicode 5.2. Your font may include the character already, but `wcwidth` does not look at which font is used.

Comment: @sid_com Unfortunately, I don't know of a better way than to check the libc documentation and/or sources and hope that it's included as a comment.

Comment: Late to the party (as usual), but I'm having this problem as well. I don't understand why locale plays into what wcwidth returns. Does the codepoint differ (visually or even in meaning) depending on which locale is used? I thought the whole point of unicode was that it is a big list of *all* characters, regardless of language. Sure, new ones might be missing from libc, but my case, however, is the swedish/german `Ö` (\u00d6) which for sure is not a new one. libc's wcwidth still returns -1 (libc 2.34).

Comment: For reference, I solved it using https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/wcwidth.c
It only supports unicode 5, however, but it returns correctly for my purposes. And it doesn't care about locale.